# Ceil number to next 100k

Tags: javascript, math

I tried to find an answer to this question but didn't find a clear simple solution.

Assume I have different numbers, for example, 90000, 125784, 547123, 18047.
Now, I need to `ceil` them to a nearest 100k so that they become:

```
90000   =>  100000
125784  =>  200000
547123  =>  600000
18047   =>  100000
```

Looks like a simple task but I have no clue how to make it work for all possible values, from 0 to a billion.

Comment: I assume you are fully aware that `yourDescribedFunction(100001)` will return `200000` ..? (Just checking.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide by 100000 before ceiling, then multiply with 100000:

```
function ceil100K (nr) {
  return Math.ceil(nr / 100000) * 100000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple:

```
Math.ceil(number/100000)*100000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
var precision = 100000,
    rounded = Math.ceil(val / precision) * precision;
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest:

```
var n = 9000,
    o = Math.ceil(n/100000) * 100000;
console.log(o);
```

Or, functionally:

```
function toNearestK (num, k) {
    return Math.ceil(num/(k*1000)) * (k * 1000);
}
```

call with:

```
toNearestK (9000, 100); // 100000
```

Comment: Nearest to 100K is required. You calculate ceiling of 10k(10000).

Comment: @Fumu7: indeed, editing and correcting the typos as you commented.